# MS Word, using NPOI library

Tags: c#, ms-office, npoi

I would like to use NPOI library to get image from Word file (Doc [97-2003]).

I want to HWPFDocument class, but i can not find namespace, where this class is. I write code in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that using NPOI.
As tonyqus (the guy behind the project) states [here](http://npoi.codeplex.com/discussions/360441) and [here](http://npoi.codeplex.com/discussions/393758) **HWPF** is not stable and usable. 
I've managed to work with MS Word and Excel with "[OpenOffice uno SDK](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Professional_UNO)".
It's not straightforward but after a little bit of struggle you can have great results.
You can read how to extract and use the assemblies [here](http://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/) and how to achieve what you're looking for [here](http://blog-of-darius.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/extract-images-from-word-openoffice.html).

Of course you can always use MSOffice Interop but you need to install MS Office on the client where the application is executed.

Hope it helps.